# Cakephp How to query the paid amount?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, sql-function, data-access

I dont know whats wrong but my code dont output the paid amount column

```
$payment_tbl = TableRegistry::get("MembershipPayment");
$payments = $payment_tbl->find();
$payments->select(['payment_total'=> $payments->func()->sum('paid_amount')]);
$this->set("payments",$payments);
```

and then echo this as echo `$payments->payment_total;`

Answer (score 2):

`$payments` will be a query result object, not a single result. With this query, where you're expecting just a single row, add `->first()` after your `sum` call.

In general, if you're not getting what you expect, dump the contents of the variable in question, like with `pr($payments)` or `debug($payments)`, that will very often very quickly give you a clear indication of what the problem is. In this case, you'll see it's not the Entity object that you're expecting.